# Wordpress website loading too slow

Tags: wordpress, performance, plugins, loading

My wordpress website [LINK](http://zigzagprinromania.com) takes 1 minute or more to load any page(front end and dashboard admin panel).The problem suddenly started today.I tried to deactivate all new installed plugin and some old plugins also.Didn't worked.Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer: after the last update of wordpress 4.0.1, 90% of wordpress websites are broken(very slow speed of loading).I will wait for the wordpress team to fix this.

Comment: Do you have any kind of link regarding that 90% figure? I'd like to investigate this further.

Comment: I'd avoid throwing around unverifiable figures like that: given that the update is only for 4.0 and usage stats for 4.0 are below 15%, I can't fathom how 90% of WP websites are broken.